# Issue doing jekyll serve

Tags: jekyll

`bundle exec jekyll build`
gets stuck after auto-regeneration

`jekyll serve --force_polling` gives me the error `uninitialized constant Bundler::Plugin::API::Source (NameError)` with the following:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:35:in `full_gem_path': uninitialized constant Bundler::Plugin::API::Source (NameError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1391:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `block in require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:823:in `block in each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:822:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:822:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in `find'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0/lib/bundler/plugin/api/source.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:35:in `full_gem_path'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1391:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `block in require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:823:in `block in each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:822:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:822:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in `find'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0/lib/bundler.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:34:in `require_from_bundler'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/exe/jekyll:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing owner of this directory to my local user.

```
chown -R myuser:mygroup /Library/Ruby/Gems
```

Comment: That did not solve the problem. 
I am using ruby 2.0.0
Here are the gems I am using :
`-bundler
-jekyll
-rack-jekyll
-jekyll-paginate
-jekyll-feed`

Comment: Removed the lock using `rm -rf Gemfile.lock` in my project directory's root folder, re-ran  `bundle install` but that didn't work either.

Comment: I removed `~/.bundle` directory, reinstalled gems, changed folder ownership and finally worked. Problem is most probably due to incorrect gems. I'm no ruby expert but it seems if you installed a gem with sudo, you may have this issue.